# GPA rater in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a GPA rater.
The problem:
Write a C++ program that asks the user for their cumulative GPA in the range [0,4]. If the GPAenter code here
is in:

1. [3-4] you say, “Superb!”
2. [2-3[ you say, “Good!”
3. [1-2[ you say, “Hmm!”
4. [0-1[ you say, “No comment!”

The program should display an error message and exit if the GPA entered exceeds 4 or less than
0.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double grade;

    cout << "Input your GPA: ";
    cin >> grade;
    cout << endl << endl;

    if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 4)
    {
        if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 1)
        {
            cout << "No comment!";
        }
        if (grade >= 1 && grade <= 2)
        {
            cout << "Hmm!";
        }
        if (grade >= 2 && grade <= 3)
        {
            cout << "Good!";
        }
        if (grade >= 3 && grade <= 4)
        {
            cout << "Superb!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error : GPA is not in the specified range";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I feel there is a more efficient way than mine.
Is there?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way is yours inefficient? I don't think you're going to get better than a few comparisons.

Comment: If `grade == 1` two messages would be printed. Consider making one of the side non-inclusive or using `else if`. https://godbolt.org/z/Pb11o1qGG

Comment: @erip Thanks for your reply. I was told it could be done in fewer lines of code, but I wasn't told how

Comment: @RetiredNinja I realized, should I use 'else if' for the rest of the 'if' statements

Comment: You can get rid of the top `if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 4)` and use else  to reduce some of the code. The last `else` block would print your error message.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better served by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to code golf it, but your code is clear.  It does check things that you already know more than once.

For example, if `(grade >= 0)`, then it still is on the next line.  If it's not `<= 1`, then it is definitely `> 1` -- you only need to check if it's `<= 2` (with `else if`).

If you want to make something silly, you could something like this (after checking if grade is in range):

```
string m[4] = {"No comment!", "Hmm!", "Good!", "Superb!"};
cout << m[min(3, int(grade))];
```

You need to add:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
```

It's fewer lines of code, but possibly not more efficient (you need to measure)